# Part of pascal function

Tags: php, pascal

I'm trying to rewrite a **pascal** program to **PHP**, and don't understand what this part of pascal function do:

```
 while (u[3] <> 1) and (u[3]<>0) and (v[3]<>0)do
       begin
       q:=u[3] div v[3];
       for i:=1 to 3 do
           begin
           t:=u[i]-v[i]*q;
           u[i]:=v[i];
           v[i]:=t;
           {writeln('u',i,'=',u[i],'  v',i,'=',v[i]); }
           end;
       end;
       if u[1]<0 then u[1]:=n+u[1];
       rae:=u[1];
```

Please help to rewrite it to PHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ($u[3] != 1) && ($u[3] != 0) && ($v[3] != 0) {
  $q = floor($u[3] / $v[3]);
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $t = $u[$i] - $v[$i] * $q;
    $u[$i] = $v[$i];
    $v[$i] = $t;
    echo "u$i={$u[$i]} v$i={$v[$i]}\n";
  }
}

if ($u[1] < 0) {
  $u[1] = $n + $u[1];
}

$rae = $u[1];
```

Comment: please describe, what does this line do "floor($u[3] / $v[3])"

Comment: Div is the integer part of the result of the division. So here, I do the division and give the result to floor, which only keeps the integer part (it's a round that always rounds down).

Answer (score 4):

A **very** literal translation of that code, should be this one:

```
while ($u[3] != 1 && $u[3] != 0 && $v[3] != 1 )
{
    $q = floor($u[3] / $v[3]);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
    {
        $t = $u[$i] - $v[$i] * $q;
        $u[$i] = $v[$i];
        $v[$i] = $t;
        //writeln('u',i,'=',u[i],'  v',i,'=',v[i]);
    }
}

if ($u[1] < 0 )
    $u1] = $n + $u[1];

$rae = $u[1];
```

Of course, u and v are arrays. Sorry for not giving any more info, but it's been like 10 years since Pascal and I last saw each other, but we had a profound romance for a long time, since I feel inlove for to hotties(C# and PHP) :)

Comment: Modulus and div are not the same. Also the for will go one less turn.

Comment: Sorry 'bout the for loop. I still think that % is the one we need, if I recall, div is used to get the remainder of the division, which is what % does.

Comment: div is used to get the integer part, mod is used to get the remainder

Comment: All right!!! Im very sorry for my ignorance!! you were right on with the **floor** function

Answer (score 3):

```
while($u[3] != 1 && $u[3] != 0 && $v[3] != 0)
{
 $q = ($u[3] - ($u[3] % $v[3]) ) / $v[3]; //just the same as floor($u[3]/$v[3]), but i want to use % here :)
 for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
 {
  $t = $u[$i] - $v[$i]*$q;
  $u[$i] = $v[$i];
  $v[$i] = $t;
  echo '<br />u'.$i.'='.$u[$i].' v'.$i.'='.$v[$i];
 }
}
if ($u[1] < 0) $u[1] = $n + $u[1];
$rae = $u[1];
```

Comment: Modulus and div are not the same.

Answer (score 3):

2 small corrections to David's code:

```
while ($u[3] != 1 && $u[3] != 0 && $v[3] != 1 )
```

should be

```
while ($u[3] != 1 && $u[3] != 0 && $v[3] != 0 )
```

and

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++)
```

i never reaches the value  of 3

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
```

May be the Writeln can be translated to

```
echo 'u'.$i.'='.$u[$i].' v'.$i.'='.$v[$i];
```

When you do the translation of arrays, take into account that arrays in php uses 0 as the first index.

```
$u= array( 3, 5, 22 )
echo u[1]; // prints 5
```

Comment: Nicely done. Good luck that you where there to correct... ;) keep up the good work

Answer (score 2):

I dont know pascal But i have tried :)

```
while ($u[3]!=1 && $u[3]!=0 && $v[3]!=0) [
    $q=floor($u[3]/ $v[3]);
    for ($i=1;$i<3;$i++) {
        $t=$u[$i]-$v[$i]*$q;
        $u[$i]=$v[$i];
        $v[$i]=$t;
        echo "u".$i."=".$u[$i]."v".$i."=".$v[$i];       
    }
    if ($u[1]<0) {
        $u[1]=$n+$u[1]; 
    }
    $rae=$u[1];
```

- **In php variable Name Start With $**
- **No Begin End used here in php only braces :)**

Comment: In Pascal div is division in which the remainder is discarded. Actually the integer part of the result.

Comment: and now this is the remainder.

Comment: @bazmegakapa now its fine same as you